# How to increase the ASPxGridView content size of pdf file in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can one increase the size of `ASPxGridView` contents while downloading in PDF format? My devexpress version is 13.2 and visual studio is 2010.

```
protected void Export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            ASPxGridView1.DataBind();
            ASPxGridViewExporter1.GridViewID = "ASPxGridView1";
            ASPxGridViewExporter1.PaperKind = System.Drawing.Printing.PaperKind.A4;
            ASPxGridViewExporter1.ReportHeader = "hello";
            ASPxGridViewExporter1.WritePdfToResponse("hello.xls");
        }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use gridview instead of aspxgridview and try this.

```
 using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                //To Export all pages
                GridView2.AllowPaging = false;
                this.BindGrid();

                GridView2.RenderControl(hw);
                StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
                Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
                HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
                pdfDoc.Open();
                htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                pdfDoc.Close();

                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.Write(pdfDoc);
                Response.End();
            }
        }
```